How to do this in Excel
Copy the following values and paste into A1:E9 cells in excel sheet.

Can you please clarify if you want to see duplicates in column E or not?

Added an answer for three criteria, for fun. All credit goes to you and Black cat.

The formula is in cell D25
=RANK.EQ($B25,$B$25:$B$32)+COUNTIFS($B$25:$B$32,$B25,$C$25:$C$32,">"&$C25)+COUNTIFS(B$24:B24,B25,C$24:C24,C25)

Since it takes one row above the table, the table cannot be started in row 1. If there is a header, then it works and return this result:


Sure because there is the header with player, points etc...

It not seems inpossible. This could be a good follow-up question.

SO members are kindly help on specific issues, but the site's aim is not producing complete and complex solutions for a problem.

What really count is that you can solve your problem. If that, you can post it as an answer also (don't add it to the question because if it is the only one it makes harder for future users to find it. Can I answer my own question

For earlier versions of Excel:
=RANK(B9, $B$2:$B$9) + COUNTIF($B$2:B9, B9) - 1 + (C9 / 100)

You have to format the numbers not to show decimal point.

If you have Excel 365 you could use:
=SORTBY(SEQUENCE(ROWS(B2:B9)), -(B2:B9 + C2:C9/100))



Using Name Manager
We could use names to shorten:

with active cell in the second row (for example H2), add these names:

rank_by =$B$2:$F$9
_1st    =INDEX(rank_by,,1)
_2nd    =INDEX(rank_by,,2)
_3rd    =INDEX(rank_by,,3)
_4th    =INDEX(rank_by,,4)
_5th    =INDEX(rank_by,,5)
cif_2   =COUNTIFS(_1st,$B2,_2nd,">"&$C2)
cif_3   =COUNTIFS(_1st,$B2,_2nd,$C2,_3rd,">"&$D2)
cif_4   =COUNTIFS(_1st,$B2,_2nd,$C2,_3rd,$D2,_4th, ">"&$E2)
cif_5   =COUNTIFS(_1st,$B2,_2nd,$C2,_3rd,$D2,_4th,$E2,_5th,">"&$F2)
cif_eq  =COUNTIFS(_1st,$B2, _2nd,$C2, _3rd,$D2,_4th,$E2,_5th,$F2) - 1


using the names (fill-down):
=RANK.EQ(B2,_1st) + cif_2 + cif_3 + cif_4 + cif_5 + cif_eq



@KramKramer, I'll post later if I could come up with a better one. I use names often as they make it easier to write and maintain formulas.

@KramKramer, sure - you too!
